# Changing user's picture in sharepoint 2010

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-import

we have a sharepoint 2010 team site as an intranet site, we have user profile which is synchronized with AD. now I want my user be able to change their picture from sharepoint(my profile>edit photo). what is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various organizational policies. For example for one of my customer SharePoint was the source. We trained users on how to modify there profile photos.

This will get exported to Active Directory.

This approach is flexible and it eases user experience. Now Active Directory Admin don't need to worry about Photos as each user is responsible for managing their own profiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the users to uplaod the pictures then OOTB control is best (my profile>edit photo). But you have to do some extra work with profile property so that once user upload the picture then it should save in the AD.

So you need to configure the Export of Profile Picture to AD.Here are brief steps:

- The connection account must have Replicate Directory Changes
  permissions on the domain. For more information, see the Grant
  Replicate Directory Changes permission on a domain section of the
  "Grant Active Directory Domain Services permissions for profile
  synchronization" procedural reference article.
- When exporting property values from SharePoint Server to AD DS, the
  synchronization account must have Create Child Objects on this object
  and all descendants and Write All Properties on this object and all
  descendants permission on the organizational unit (OU) that is being
  synchronized with SharePoint 2010.For more information, see the Grant
  Create Child Objects and Write permission section of the "Grant
  Active Directory Domain Services permissions for profile
  synchronization" procedural reference article.
- The account for the User Profile Synchronization Service (not the
  connection account) requires local administrator rights on the
  SharePoint server running the synchronization service.
- Locate the user profile property named “Picture” in the user profile service application in Central Administration.
- Edit the property and set up an export to the Active Directory field “thumbnailPhoto”. Map and select **"export"**. Click Add
- Once done, please run the full sync.

[Configure SharePoint 2010 to Export Profile Pictures to AD](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2784927)